# loader image hanged making service calls in Angular js

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I making service calls, i am showing loader image, but i my service calls are more than 1000 calls.that time loader image not working it is not animated it seems stroking.

My HTML:

```
<div>
   <img src="imageName" ng-hide="loader">
<div>
```

Mycontroller:

```
var i =0;
$scope.loader = true;
myArray.forEach(function(){
    myService.getCall(item,function(){
      i =i +1;
      success call back;
      if( i == myArray.lenght){
          $scope.loader = false;
        }

         },function(){
      error call back
})
})
```

Comment: What do you want to do? where is code of service that you are talking about?

Comment: Why have you put myService.getCall() within forEach()?  what is your scenario?

Comment: i need make list of array calls. that list contain 1000 objects. @micronyks

Comment: so you want is, when call is going on you want to show loader img. right?

Comment: kind of weird implementation you have, i'd say. Callback will cause a problem.

Comment: Can you give me the better solution this one please. @micronyks

Comment: Yes I can do it. But I dont know why are you making calls 1000 times. better solution would be collect your 1000 objects at clientside and make a list of it. pass that list to the sever and do whatever you want to do with those 1000 objects at serverside. after that manipulation come back to client side and hide your img....

Comment: No we don't have server side permission to do. we have only one choice to do client side. @micronyks